# Can't retrieve data using php

Tags: php

I am trying to retrieve the data from `leave_balance.php` and pass it to `employee.php`, but the data is NULL.

Here is the script `leave_balance.php`:

```
if($lid=="1")

    $bal = $bal + $replacementleave;
```

Here is the script `employee.php`:

```
$bal = $rowe[bal];
```

then I call `$bal` on the html page:

```
<input type='text' value='$bal'>
```

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Have you included leave_balance.php on employee.php, or are you using `$_POST` or `$_GET` to retrieve the values, or a Session?

Comment: How are those two PHP files related?  And how are you persisting the value from one to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly use `$bal` from the otehr file. Instead you can use the [**Session variables**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). Just like this-

**employee.php:**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['bal']= $rowe[bal];
```

**leave_balance.php:**

```
if($lid=="1")
   $_SESSION['bal'] = $_SESSION['bal'] + $replacementleave;
```

**Also,** you cannot use the php variable inside the `html` directly. To use the php var inside your html text-

```
<input type='text' value="<?php echo $_SESSION['bal']; ?>">
```

or, you can also `echo` the html statement-

```
echo  "<input type='text' value='".$_SESSION['bal']."'>";
```